# Using trailing slashes as GET variables in PHP with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm currently trying to create a `.htaccess` file that essentially converts this:

[From] `http://www.example.com/pagename.php?1=name&2=email&3=hash` 
[To] `http://www.example.com/pagename/name/email/hash`

Which can then be read in PHP as `$name = $_GET[1]; $email = $_GET[2]` and so on...

Where `pagename` is equal to the filename without the file extension and then every trailing slash after that is set as a new GET variable incrementing by one (in a way that you could theoretically define unlimited trailing slashes and it would continue to increment these `$_GET` variables by one.

Anyone know how?

Comment: No time for "real" answer right now, but: search for PATH_INFO here on SO.

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a try. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want there to be an arbitrary number of variables, you need to turn on *Multiviews* then add some code to your php scripts to look at the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` variable. So something like this:

```
$data = explode("/",trim($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"],"/"));

$length = count($data);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
  $_GET[$i] = $data[$i-1];
}
```

to populate the `$_GET` variable with all the path elements.

Then in htaccess, you need something like this to append the `php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)$ /$1.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: Awesome, this works a treat! I will never forget this implementation.

Comment: @JohnLin I have a new problem: So far I'm using this HTACCESS file to process my variables:

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)$ /$1.php$2 [L]

This is an example of one of my URLs

`example.com/browse/search/queryhere`

Basically I now need to implement this into a form where the form submits and places the `GET` variable in place of `queryhere` in the same format as the rest of the URL...

Any ideas? I'm getting `example.com/browse/search/?q=something` which isn't what I need.